# Convert a YAML to string in Helm

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have an helm chart used to deploy an application that have configuration file in YAML format.
Currently, my helm chart use the following code:

*values.yaml*

```yaml
databaseUser: "dbuser"

configFiles:
  db_config_file.yaml: |-
    databaseUser: {{ .Values.databaseUser }}
    databasePort: 1234
    [...]

[...]
```

**templates/configmap.yaml**

```yaml
data:
  {{- range $name, $config := .Values.configFiles }}
  {{ $name }}: |-
{{ tpl $config $ | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```

This code allow me to change easily the `databaseUser` from values, but the problem is that if I want to change the value of `databasePort`, I have to rewrite the entire configuration like that:

```yaml
configFiles:
  db_config_file.yaml: |-
    databaseUser: {{ .Values.databaseUser }}
    databasePort: 9876
```

which is inconvenient. It works like that because the `db_config_file.yaml` content is interpreted as string because I give it to the `tpl` function which only accept strings.

So my question is, is there a way to convert the YAML to string in a Helm template and get the following things:

```yaml
databaseUser: "dbuser"

configFiles:
  db_config_file.yaml: # Content is not a string block
    databaseUser: {{ .Values.databaseUser }}
    databasePort: 1234
    [...]

[...]
```

```yaml
data:
  {{- range $name, $config := .Values.configFiles }}
  {{ $name }}: |-
{{ tpl (<a toString function> $config) $ | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve a similar issue using the code below

*values.yaml*

```
databaseUser: "dbuser"

configFiles: # Content is not a string block
  db_config_file_yaml: 
    databaseUser: {{ .Values.databaseUser }}
    databasePort: 1234
[...]
```

*templates/configmap.yaml*

```
data:
   db_config_file.yaml: |
{{ .Values.configFiles.db_config_file_yaml | toYaml | indent 4 }}
```

Reference: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#strings-in-yaml

Comment: This was so close to the answer for me. The one thing missing was to pass the values through `tpl` so the final solution was `{{ tpl (toYaml .Values.configFiles.db_config_file_yaml ) . | indent 4 }}`

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider templating `databasePort` as well and wrapping your values in double quotes?

*values.yaml*

```
databaseUser: "dbuser"
databasePort: 1234

configFiles:
  db_config_file.yaml: |-
    databaseUser: "{{ .Values.databaseUser }}"
    databasePort: "{{ .Values.databasePort }}"
```

Comment: Yes I consider that, but the problem is that I don't know by advance every property that will be use (it is use to configure endpoints to apis and we don't know how many)

Comment: @Guillaume you can export your properties into environment variables, use placeholders like `$DATABASE_PORT` in `values.yaml` and use `envsubst` to update them in-place in file or use `--set databasePort=$DATABASE_PORT` in your command

Answer (score 2):

as your question helped me to solve mine, maybe I can help you with my little knowledge.
[The official helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#scalar-types-in-yaml) describes a way to enforce type inference:

```
coffee: "yes, please"
age: !!str 21
port: !!int "80"
```

HTH,
Martin

Comment: I'm sorry but that works when declaring variables, not afterwards to convert a variable to another type