# helm chart: Include multiple lines from values.yaml into configmap

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to create a helm chart that results in a config map that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
data:
  myconfigfile1.properties: |
    property11 = value11
    property12 = value12
  myconfigfile1.properties: |
    property21 = value21
    property22 = value22
```

whereas this part shall be configurable in the `values.yaml`:

```
myconfig:
  myconfigfile1.properties: |
    property11 = value11
    property12 = value12
  myconfigfile1.properties: |
    property21 = value21
    property22 = value22
```

Now I want to iterate over all the children of `myconfig` in the `values.yaml` and add them to my helm template. My attempts so far with this template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
data: 
  # {{- range $key, $val := .Values.myconfig}}
  # {{ $key }}: |
  #   {{ $val }}
  # {{- end }}
```

resulted in this error message:

```
$ helm install --dry-run --debug ./mychart/ --generate-name
install.go:159: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:176: [debug] CHART PATH: /home/my/helmcharts/mychart
Error: YAML parse error on mychart/templates/myconfig.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':'
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':'
YAML parse error on mychart/templates/myconfig.yaml
```

I can avoid the error by removing the `|` after `myconfigfile1.properties:` in my `values.yaml`, however then I lose the line breaks and the result is not what I want.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Kind regards,
Martin

Answer (score 9):

A few minutes after writing this question I stubled upon [Question #62432632 convert-a-yaml-to-string-in-helm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432632/convert-a-yaml-to-string-in-helm) which does not exactly answer my question but with its help I could find the correct syntax.

`values.yaml`:

```
myconfig:
  myconfigfile1.properties: |-
    property11 = value11
    property12 = value12

  myconfigfile2.properties: |-
    property21 = value21
    property22 = value22
```

template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
data: 
{{- range $name, $config := .Values.myconfig }}
  {{ $name }}: |-
{{ tpl $config $ | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```